# Using qrc to extract bundled zip files

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qresource

I tried this code where it extract the bundled zip files from compiled qrc but it gives me error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ':/files/file.zip'
```

Any help/suggestions?

```py
import zipfile
import resources

zf = zipfile.ZipInfo(":/files/file.zip")
for file in zf.infolist():
    zf.extract(file)
```

Comment: Based on the error message, your ZipInfo argument ```":/files/file.zip"``` seems to be incorrect, try ```"files/file.zip"```

Comment: @itprorh66 the OP is trying to read a Qt resource file, which has the `:` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

zipfile is a module that is not designed to be used with Qt directly, instead you must extract the bytes and use a BytesIO as an intermediary:

```py
import io
import sys
import zipfile

import resource_rc

from PyQt5 import QtCore


file = QtCore.QFile(":/files/file.zip")
if not file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly):
    print(file.errorString())
    sys.exit(-1)

ba = file.readAll()
f = io.BytesIO(ba)

with zipfile.ZipFile(f, "r") as zf:
    for file in zf.infolist():
        data = zf.extract(file)
        print(data)
```